# I can't get VS2012 to open its Rule Condition Editor Dialog to modify a WWF 3.5 workflow IfElseBranchActivity

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, workflow-foundation

I am maintaining some code that contains a WWF 3.5 sequential workflow. (It's part of a larger C# code base being maintained in VS2012.) I need to edit the workflow's logic by altering a declarative rule condition expression in an IfElseBranchActivity.

When I view the Properties for the IfElseBranchActivity in question, and then attempt to open the Rule Condition Editor Dialog (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb483183.aspx) I run into trouble. There are two symptoms:

First, if I click somewhere in the Condition Name field value, and I click the ellipsis button that appears on the right side of that field, I'm presented with the Select Condition Dialog box. If I then select the condition belonging to the IfElseBranchActivity in question, and click the Dialog's Edit button, the Select Condition Dialog box vanishes. So, I can't edit the condition.

Second, if I click somewhere in the Expression field value, and I click the ellipsis button that appears on the right side of that field, I'm presented with an error message that reads:

"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Interception, Version=2.1.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

What do I need to do in order to work around this problem?

Should I install MS Unity? If so, I how do I install it such that it's available to VS2012?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I've successfully worked through the problem by following these steps:

1. I installed "Microsoft Unity 2.1" from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17866.
2. I added Unity's path (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Unity Application Block 2.1\Bin) to my system PATH env var.
3. I restarted VS2012, opened the applicable .sln, access the Properties of the IfElseBranchActivity in question, and
4. I successfully opened the Rule Condition Editor dialog.

I had further troubles within this dialog, however, but I was able to work through those as well. (I had to delete and recreate rules rather than edit them because of error messages that the dialog presented to me...)

Wish me luck in remembering to remove Unity from my system PATH var when I'm done making changes to the workflow in question :>.